# connect razorsql to my hsqldb located on a VPS

Tags: hsqldb, vps, razorsql

My database is an `HSQLDB` located on my `VPS` online, how can I configure `razorsql` to connect to that DB ?

I am installing `razorsql` on my local PC at home

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the HSQLDB server on the VPS. You can then connect with a URL such as this:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://nameofserver/dbname
```